# Showing part of an external sheet in a pop-up in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have two spreadsheets.  The first has a table of numbers.  The second has formatted text cells.  When the user clicks on a cell in the first spreadsheet, I want to show a range of formatted cells from the second sheet.

It seems like MsgBox is too limited for this. How can I create a custom pop-up? I know that to get the contents of the cell range as originally formatted I can use the camera Quick-Access tool.  With this I could create a set of static images containing the cell ranges from the second sheet.  But I want the user to be able to show only one image at a time when clicking on a given cell.  Can I select an image from a cell to show in a comment?

Answer (score 0):

**This VBA code (Macro) will help you to Pop up related data from the Target Sheet.**

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A9")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim DataSheet As Range

Set DataSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A17:F24")

Str1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target, DataSheet, 2, False)
Str2 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target, DataSheet, 3, False)
Str3 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target, DataSheet, 4, False)
Str4 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target, DataSheet, 5, False)
Str5 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target, DataSheet, 6, False)

MsgBox Str1 & vbCr & Str2 & vbCr & Str3 & vbCr & Str4 & vbCr & Str5, vbOKOnly, "Data to Display"

End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- *Mechanism behind this code is `VLOOKUP` function:*
- As soon you click any of the cells in Source Sheet between `Range (A1:A9)`, this code will search & display corresponding Data from Target Sheet (Sheet 2 `Range (A17:F24))`.

**N.B.**

- In this code Sheet name, Column position 
  references (with Vlookup) are editable.
- Adjust cell references in this code as needed.

Comment: Rajesh, How do I show formatted strings from Sheet2 in a pop-up.  MsgBox cannot do that?

Comment: @user823527,, yes using Msgbox formatted text can't be included,, the only way I can find is link between Sheets or give me some time to find other way !!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to code your own dialog in VB.
The Msgbox is - as the name says - for text messages to the user.